symfony choicetype multiple display selected values
I'm stuck on a problem with Symfony 7 with choicetype using Mulitple mode.
There is something weird,
I'got an array including groups for choices.
->add('Groups', ChoiceType::class, ["attr" => ["class" => "form-control shadow-none pt-2", "multiple" => true ], "label" => "User Mgr. Group", 'help' => 'Select one or multiple Groups.', 'data' => ['Test Group', 'All Users'] ,'choices' => $gps])

$gps being an array like this: ["All Users" => "1", "Test Group" => "2" ].
If I set it up like this, I've got a Warning: Array to string conversion
However, if the array is: ["All Users" => true, "Test Group" => true ], then I'm displaying the list (Weird).
My goal is to display a group list with their index as value.So, If I select all groups, the selectbox should send all.
When I receive the data, I need to display this when the user is in multiple groups like this..

I used : 'data' => ['Test Groups', 'All Users'] but whatever I set for tests, no way.
What's the good practice to do that please?
I tried to read the Symfony document and some threads here, but not found.
I already used choicetype in my form, that work with simple code (not multiple) and with an array like this:
'choices'  => [
            'Yes' => "yes",
            'No' => "no",
        ],

I don't understand why it wont works.
I don't have much experiences on Symfony sorry.

I'm moving forward on this issue.
on the builder, I put @ like this.
$form = @$this->createFormBuilder($jsonData)

Looks good but with the option data, who to select multiple selection?
In my exemple, If I set 'data' => '1', the choice 1 is selected. If I set 'data' => '2', the choice 2 is selected.
I'd like to know how to select all with data?
I tried to set 'data' => ['1', '2'] , no way.

Fixed.
->add('Groups', ChoiceType::class, ["attr" => ["class" => "form-control shadow-none pt-2"], "multiple" => true , "expanded" => false, "label" => "User Mgr. Group", 'help' => 'Select one or multiple Groups.', 'data' => ['Test Group', 'All Users'] ,'choices' => $gps])

Multiple and expanded was set in the wrong place.
